# When can an object have either but not both of non zero size , one or more bytes of storage?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

C++ 14 intro.cpp States:

```
a most derived object shall have a non-zero size and shall occupy one or more bytes of storage
```

Why did they have to state

> non-zero size

and

> one or more bytes of storage

When can it have one but not the other ?

Comment: 1 bit would be non-zero size I guess but wouldnt be at least 1 byte or more of storage... thats all i can think of

Comment: @Borgleader Object size is always a whole number of bytes.

Comment: @n.m. I know that but maybe thats the part of the standard that states that, ive never read the entire thing. why else would they specify non-zero and then "1 or more bytes"? Clarity?

Comment: I'd say, it's just the standard repeating the same thing in different words in an unnecessary attempt to make sure it's not misunderstood. But I may be wrong, and they did think the repetition was of value.

Answer (score 4):

The two parts are actually saying different things.

> a most derived object shall have a non-zero size

That means `sizeof` using an object will return a non-zero size.

> a most derived object ... shall occupy one or more bytes of storage

That means the object occupies some bytes (one or more) of memory.

If the second statement didn't exist then that could mean that `sizeof` would report a non-zero size but the object might not actually use any memory.

Without the first statement it could mean that `sizeof` could return zero but the object would still take up space in memory.

Both are needed and orthogonal to each other.

Comment: What use does sizeof have if it doesn't return the number of bytes needed for storage?

Comment: @MikeMB - Think "empty base optimization". No storage is "really" occupied by the sub-object. That's why the emphasis on "most derived".

Comment: @ StoryTeller: Good example. I also forgot about alignment / padding. I think the answer could profit from a short explanation of what size of returns (space needed in array) and why that is not necessarily the same as occupied storage.

Answer (score 3):

There are cases in which a class may have a **non-zero** size (returned by `sizeof`) but it does not actually occupy any space on memory. For example, [**Empty Base Optimization (EBO)**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) is used to make a **base part** of a derived object occupies no space on memory as shown in example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Base {};

struct Derived : Base
{
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    printf("sizeof(Base) = %d\n", sizeof(Base));

    Derived* p = new Derived;
    void* p1 = p;
    void* p2 = &p->a;

    if(p1 == p2) { printf("Good compiler\n"); }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with gcc 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

Output:

```
sizeof(Base) = 1
Good compiler
```